# Aligning inner contents with the contents of nearby divs

Tags: html, css

If you look at the demo in fullscreen, I'm trying to align all of the inner contents of each div - e.g. You'll notice that the middle cyan div’s contents are not aligned equally with the first and third cyan divs’ contents.

It's difficult to explain, but look at the position of the icon in the middle cyan div compared to the others. If there's a different amount of text inside of each div, how can I make it so that the inner contents are all aligned vertically with the other cyan divs?

```css
.sections {
    background: #f2f2f2;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px 10%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#foster-cta-wrap {
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.foster-cta {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 250px;min-width: 250px;
    height: 200px;
    background: cyan;
    border: 1px solid grey;
    margin-top: 30px;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    display: inline-flex;
}
.foster-top {
    display: block;
    font-size: 30px;
}
.foster-middle {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.foster-bottom {
    display: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.foster-cta:hover {
    background: lightgreen;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.foster-top a:link, .foster-top a:visited, .foster-middle a:link, .foster-middle a:visited, .foster-bottom a:link, .foster-bottom a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #333;
}
```

```html
<section class="sections">
<article id="foster-cta-wrap">
        <nav class="foster-cta">
            <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
            <span class="foster-middle"><a href="#">search engine optimisation</a></span>
            <span class="foster-bottom">increase the rankings in search results.</span>
        </nav><!--
        --><nav class="foster-cta">
            <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
            <span class="foster-middle"><a href="#">SEO</a></span>
            <span class="foster-bottom">increase the rankings in search results.</span>
        </nav><!--
        --><nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="foster-cta">
            <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
            <span class="foster-middle"><a href="#">search engine optimisation</a></span>
            <span class="foster-bottom">increase the rankings in search results.</span>
        </nav>
        </article>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
  .sections {
        background: #f2f2f2;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 100px 10%;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #foster-cta-wrap {
        background: yellow;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        flex-direction: row;
        align-items: center;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
    .foster-cta {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        width: 250px;min-width: 250px;
        height: 200px;
        background: cyan;
        border: 1px solid grey;
        margin-top: 30px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .foster-top {
        display: block;
        font-size: 30px;
        padding: .5em;
    }
    .foster-middle {
        display: block;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        font-size: 22px;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .foster-bottom {
        display: block;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 16px;
    }
    .foster-cta:hover {
        background: lightgreen;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .foster-top a:link, .foster-top a:visited, .foster-middle a:link, .foster-middle a:visited, .foster-bottom a:link, .foster-bottom a:visited {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
    }
```

```html
    <section class="sections">
    <article id="foster-cta-wrap">
            <nav class="foster-cta">
                <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
                <span class="foster-middle"><a href="#">search engine optimisation</a></span>
                <span class="foster-bottom">increase the rankings in search results.</span>
            </nav>
            <nav class="foster-cta">
                <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
                <span class="foster-middle"><a href="#">SEO</a></span>
                <span class="foster-bottom">increase the rankings in search results.</span>
            </nav>
            <nav onclick="location.href='#';" class="foster-cta">
                <span class="foster-top">icon</span>
                <span class="foster-middle"><a href="#">search engine optimisation</a></span>
                <span class="foster-bottom">increase the rankings in search results.</span>
            </nav>
            </article>
    </section>
```

This is what I would do: I removed all the flex formatting on `.foster-cta` and replaced it with `text-align: center;`. Then, I added padding to `.foster-top` to make it look nicer and not contact the other text. The caption is now pushed up against the main title, but this can be fixed by setting `padding` / `margin` values for either of them.

Comment: I see what you've done here. but is there a way to make the other classes (foster-middle and bottom) automatically aligned?

Comment: @user8758206 When you say "aligned", what exactly are you looking for? As far as I can tell, all of their text will still be center-aligned in the respective boxes.

Comment: I mean make the three inner divs are on the same lines as the other inner divs - it's difficult to explain